# What am I doing wrong with simple Mongoose unique validation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've read the docs as well as the other Stack Overflow posts, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here... This should be a simple validation to check for a unique string and according to the docs and other Stack Overflow articles, this should raise an error and not save a duplicate record. In this case, it appears to simply not validate at all...

I have tried dropping the entire collection and running the app again only to find the same behavior.

I'm following the recommended way of validating as described in [this post](http://nraj.tumblr.com/post/38706353543/handling-uniqueness-validation-in-mongo-mongoose).

Thanks in advance for helping me. New to NodeJS.

**bucket.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bucketSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

var Bucket = mongoose.model('Bucket', bucketSchema);

module.exports = Bucket;
```

**app.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Require data models
var Bucket = require('./models/bucket.js');

// Connect to database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/tritonia");
mongoose.set('debug' ,true);

// Test
var bucket = new Bucket({ name: "foo" });
bucket.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Saved");
  }
});
var bucket2 = new Bucket({ name: "foo" });
bucket2.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Test failed: It should not save a second bucket named 'foo'");
  }
})
```

**Output:**

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Mongoose: buckets.ensureIndex({ name: 1 }) { safe: undefined, background: true, unique: true }
Mongoose: buckets.insert({ __v: 0, created_at: new Date("Mon, 16 Dec 2013 02:27:39 GMT"), _id: ObjectId("52ae651baabf290436000001"), name: 'foo' }) {}
Mongoose: buckets.insert({ __v: 0, created_at: new Date("Mon, 16 Dec 2013 02:27:39 GMT"), _id: ObjectId("52ae651baabf290436000002"), name: 'foo' }) {}
Saved
Test failed: It should not save a second bucket named 'foo'
```

**DB console:**

```
> db.buckets.find()
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae6427a58628cd34000001"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:23:35.052Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae6427a58628cd34000002"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:23:35.056Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae6447d0ac5a0e35000001"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:24:07.413Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae6447d0ac5a0e35000002"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:24:07.416Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae64f02876b7d535000001"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:26:56.642Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae64f02876b7d535000002"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:26:56.645Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae650caeda67f435000001"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:27:24.646Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae650caeda67f435000002"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:27:24.689Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae651baabf290436000001"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:27:39.136Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "name" : "foo", "_id" : ObjectId("52ae651baabf290436000002"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T02:27:39.140Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
var Bucket = mongoose.model('Bucket', bucketSchema);
Bucket.on('index', function() {
   new Bucket({}).save();
   new Bucket({}).save();
   new Bucket({}).save();
   new Bucket({}).save();
})
```

You can also separate create db in installation phase, that is the best way for having index before using.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man I figured this out after much head banging.

The issue is that all the commands are happening asynchronously!

This is what is happening:

1. Setting the schema in Mongoose will run ensureIndex on 'buckets' collection with unique index on 'name' (this runs in the background and doesn't finish before number 2 runs).
2. Run insert on bucket. This writes to the database and INVALIDATES number 1. So number 1 actually FAILS to create the index. So number 3 runs...
3. Run insert on bucket with same name - There is no longer a unique index so it will write.

You have to make sure that ensureIndex runs and has, in fact, created the index before you start trying to write to it.

Leo